# Customize the look of the table of content of beamer theme Boadilla

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I want to get rid of the numbered circles in the table of content:

[image: screenshot]

And have normal text, like "1. First Section" "1.1 First Subsection" and so on.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Boadilla}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{First Section}

\begin{frame}
Frame 1
\end{frame}

\subsection{First Subsection}

\begin{frame}
Frame 2
\end{frame}

\section{Second Section}

\begin{frame}
Frame 3
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `sections numbered` and `subsections numbered` templates for the toc:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Boadilla}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[subsections numbered]

\setbeamertemplate{subsubsection in toc}{%
    \leavevmode\normalsize\usebeamerfont{subsection in
    toc}\leftskip=2.5em\usebeamerfont{subsubsection in toc}%
  \rlap{\hskip-3em\inserttocsectionnumber.\inserttocsubsectionnumber.\inserttocsubsubsectionnumber}\inserttocsubsubsection\par}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{First Section}

\begin{frame}
Frame 1
\end{frame}

\subsection{First Subsection}

\subsubsection{subsubsection name}

\begin{frame}
Frame 2
\end{frame}

\section{Second Section}

\begin{frame}
Frame 3
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sam, how, can I numerize the subsubsections? `\setbeamertemplate{subsubsection in toc}[subsubsections numbered]` does not work.. :/

Comment: @mrbela Subsubsections are not full supported by beamer

Comment: @mrbela Please see my updated answer -- although using subsubsections is in most cases not a good idea.

Comment: @mrbela Can you please go back to your previous questions and accept the answers if they solve your question?